# Apply this regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I wrote this wonderful regex and I was able to implement this:

```
s/(?:[aeiou\u00E4\u00E4\u00F6\u00D6\u00FC\u00DC])h//ig
```

in perl, however I seem to be to retarded to apply it in my Java code. I've tried the following:

`bar.replaceAll("?:[aeiou\u00E4\u00E4\u00F6\u00D6\u00FC\u00DC])h", "");`

but I seem to lack something special.

My question therefore is quite obvious: how do I apply this regex to a string in Java?

Comment: And how do you want to apply it? On what string? What do you want to extract?

Comment: Do you need to escape the slashes?

Comment: I have a string (e.g. fahst) and want to extract the h after the a. In general I want to replace exactly one h after a vowel or a german umlaut (represented by the unicode chars in this regex). so "fahst" should be replaced by "fast" but "fahhst" should be replaced by "fahst".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to double your backslashes in a Java string:

```
bar.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou\\u00E4\\u00E4\\u00F6\\u00D6\\u00FC\\u00DC]h", "");
```

The `(?i)` at the start replaces the `/i` case-insensitivity modifier.

If you want to keep the vowel and only remove the `h`, use a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
bar.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=[aeiou\\u00E4\\u00E4\\u00F6\\u00D6\\u00FC\\u00DC])h", "");
```

Comment: this is correct, howsoever I seem to have made a mistake in my regex :/
 given my previous comment as instruction, do you see the mistake?

Comment: Easy, just change the non-capturing group into a lookbehind assertion.

Comment: could you help me out with that? I'm quite new to regex

Comment: @user1867234: Already did :)